# Using jts topology suite with android

Tags: android, eclipse, jts

I try to use  " jts topology suite " libs with android using eclips:
I refers libraries with the "build path"
I compile the code

```
    package com.example.xxx;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GeometryFactory gf=new GeometryFactory();



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is     present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

application start on phone and after that it stops
I get this in the log

```
10-08 22:10:13.777: W/dalvikvm(30262): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 638 (Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/GeometryFactory;) in Lcom/example/xxx/MainActivity;
```

how I can repair it,
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jts libs works perfectly, it was a problem in my buildpath